# Compare a cell with column A and write X if Matches in Column B

Tags: excel, vba

I have been trying to find something that can help me online but no luck. I am trying to compare a value in column A with a value in Cell E1 and if match I want to put an X in column B next to the match in Column A.

here is my code I go so far:

```
     Option Explicit
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim a As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim x As Range
Dim y As Range

a = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
i = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("E1")
x = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B1:a")
y = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:a")

'For Each cell In y
    'if y = i then
        'print "X" in column B next to the value              


   'MsgBox (i)
End Sub
```

thanks for your help in advance
Dan

Comment: `"B1:a"` and `"A1:a"` are not valid range references. Also it's not clear why you are using the `SelectionChange` event.

Comment: Why not use a worksheet formula instead of VBA? Sounds like a basic `VLOOKUP` with an `IF`?

Comment: True that and I normally do use the formula for that but I am trying to learn vba for an other project I am working on. This is just the start. The later vba code I hope will do a few more things down the road. The "B1:a" is not a proper range I know but I was trying to have a flexible range cause the length of the range changes. Thank you for your input though.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few things here that are worth mentioning. When you want to specify a range using `.Range` you have to specify the columns on both sides of the `:` ; furthermore, it takes a string. This means that what you're passing is `"B1:a"` which doesn't make sense to the computer because it doesn't know you want it to use the value of `a` instead of the letter. You need to pass `"B1:B" & a` to the `.Range`. What this does is concatenate the value you found in the variable a to the string so it appears as one string to the computer.

I personally think it's easier to take all of the values as a column vector instead of dimming the `x`'s as a `range` because it makes the iteration a little easier. Instead of keeping track of what row I'm on, `Counter` will always tell me where I am since I'm just moving down a single column. As an added bonus, this  reduces the times you access the worksheet which helps speed up your macro.

Although it's commented out, it's worth noting that the loop at the bottom of your sub wouldn't work because you haven't properly closed off the if or the for.

I'm not sure what you intended this for, but it's never a bad idea to use meaningful names so you can look back on your code and figure it out without too much effort. For example, I've renamed your `a` variable to `lastrow` which at a glance describes what value it stores.

Below your code that I've altered

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim lastrow As Long
Dim Criteria As Long
Dim x() As Variant
Dim Counter As Long

lastrow = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Criteria = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("E1").Value
x = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B1:B" & lastrow).value

For Counter = 1 To UBound(x)
    If x(Counter,1) = Criteria Then
        Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Counter, "B").Value = "X"
    End If
Next Counter
MsgBox (Criteria)
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you all for your help. I'll try your suggestions when I get home.

Comment: @SJR you're absolutely right, my mistake. I'll change it now

Answer (score 1):

I little bit different approach. This find the last row in column A.
I also included if you want to match by wildcard, i.e. you want to find 45 in 645.

```
Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange()
Dim lrow As Integer
Dim a As Integer
Dim i As String
Dim Val As String

lrow = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row 'Find last row
i = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("E1") 'Set cell where compare value is

For a = 1 To lrow 'Loop from row 1 to last row in column A
    Val = Cells(a, "A").Value 'Set value to compare in Column A
    'If Val Like "*" & i & "*" Then 'Use this if you want to find 45 in 645, so wildcard
        If Val = i Then 'Exact match
            Cells(a, "B").Value = "X" 'Put X in column B
        End If
Next a
MsgBox "Match Criteria: " & (i)
End Sub
```

Comment: If your Val is changing within each loop couldn't you replace the Val in the if statement with actual value you're setting it equal to?

Comment: Thank you very much. This helps me a lot. Gonna try it out once I get home.

Comment: No problem just fun to write (could be a lot nicer, for example good behavior is to write: `For i = 1 To lrow`, but the letter was taken ;]). I think it might be quite easy to follow the steps and logic :), I've tested it so hopefully it should work for you too :)!, don't hesitate to ask if there're something unclear :)

Comment: This works great! Nice of you to put in the extra wildcard line. Thank you again.

Comment: Please mark either my or @Brotato's answer as accepted if you think you got a complete answer from either of us (marker under the voting buttons), so other people can see that the question is completed.

Comment: [Accepting Answers: How does it work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235)